# Combine regular expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirements are to allow a certain field to be 3-50 characters long, to contain alphanumeric and the '-' character, yet not allow 2 specific words.

I started with `/^[\w\-\s]{3,50}$/`. I then added `/^((?!word1).)*$/i`, `/^((?!word2).)*$/i`, etc.

I know that generally speaking, there's no logical `AND` for regexp. I can probably test the 3 regexs in a row, and fail if any of them fail, but I'd rather have a single regexp. What regular expression can I use to satisfy all 3 conditions?

Comment: Specific words blacklisting can be done without Regexps, using string methods

Comment: You really should keep them as separate regexes, absent a strong reason not to.  It is easier to understand, less error-prone, and may be more efficient as well (depending on the use case).

Comment: it's likely simpler to replace() bad stuff (instead of test/match) and check to see if the result is identical to the input. this let's you assert positively and thus makes it easy to whiltelist.

Comment: Running each test individually will allow you to provide more specific error messages to the user, possibly resulting in a better experience.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - functionally, they are all correct. We have a logic in place that applies a single regexp to every field, and I was trying to work within it. If it gets more complex, I guess I'll have to break it, but for now, I'm looking for a single expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single regex using negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*?(word1|word2))[\w\s-]{3,50}$/i
```